# Get rows on first table not on left join's result set

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables.

`TableA`

- Id
- Column 1
- Column 2

`TableB` (n-1 mapping with `TableA`)

- Column 1
- Column 2
- fkToTableAonIdentity

and my query is

```
DECLARE @Offset = 0,
DECLARE @pageSize = 10

SELECT 
    A.column1, B.Column1  
FROM 
    TableA AS A 
LEFT JOIN 
    TABLEB AS TABLE B 
ORDER BY  
    B.Column2 DESC
    OFFSET @Offset ROWS 
    FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
```

I was trying to fetch 10 rows from `tableA` joining data for `tableB`
but the query will only return exact 10 rows from the set created by left join, but I needed 10 rows of data from `table A`, so in set of left join number of rows may vary for each record in TableA.

How can I get the desired result?

**Update**:

I am using the above query in my stored procedure where `@pageSize` will be a parameter to the stored procedure.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: updated the tag, @nscheaffer  `sql-server-08`

Comment: SQL Server 2008 doesn't have `OFFSET ... FETCH` yet - that was introduced in SQL Server **2012**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use following syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Table1) ST1
JOIN Table2 ON ST1.Id=Table2.FkToT1
```

I expect your query will look as following one:

```
SELECT ST1.Col1, T2.Col1 FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM Table1
    ORDER BY Col1
    OFFSET @offset ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @page ROWS ONLY
) ST1
JOIN Table2 T2 ON ST1.Id=T2.FkToT1
```

Comment: You need an order by in that subquery or you don't know which rows you will get.